# problem with gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why my computer can`t run gazebo. my computer:intel(R)Core(TM)2 Duo CPU  T6600 @2.2GHZ 2.20GHz,RAM(2GB),NVIDIA GEForce G 103M.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56564/problem-with-gazebo/) by [yangtao09](https://answers.ros.org/users/4315/yangtao09/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-27

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-02-27**:
It lacks the appropriate RS232/IDE/Infiniband interface module.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-02-27**:
In all seriousness, there's nowhere near enough information here to answer your question. At a minimum, please provide specs for your computer including RAM, CPU type and speed, GPU model, Operating System version, Gazebo version and any errors you get when you try to run gazebo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you might want to post this question on http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0